# Логическая операция в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, if, datagridview

Есть DataGridView с автоматическим заполнением строк. Необходимо скрывать всех кто не на втором курсе и со стипендией, то есть должны оставаться строки "имя - 2 - 0" все остальные скрываться, мне помогли с написанием форича который это делает. но я теперь не могу понять почему он скрывает не очень хорошо, ведь по конструкции в if, кажется я прописал всё верно. Else не катит ибо выдает ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, выкладывайте код в виде кода, а не в виде картинки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать операцию логического сложения `||`. Возвращает true, если хотя бы один из операндов возвращает true.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  if (row.Cells[2].Value != null && ((int)row.Cells[1].Value != 2 || (int)row.Cells[2].Value != 0))
  {
     row.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Дело в том что я уже так пробовал. Вот результат выполнения программы http://prntscr.com/lrv32a

Comment: @ДмитрийКотовский, не правильно понял задачу. отредактировал ответ.

Comment: ага, заметил, сразу же попробовал - работает. Спасибо. Это вы кстати мне помогали ранее с этой задачей))